# which browsers can cache files with query string?

Tags: url, caching, query-string

To avoid browser keeping old files (img, js, css), I add file last modified date (in UNIX timestamp) to end of file name.

So, the url is something like this:

```
http://example.com/css/style.css?1372162216
```

As you see, the query string is always the same (expect when file replaced with a new version), and it can be cached.

But, the question is, Can browsers cache this file (url)? With the query string...

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: @RoyDictus: because I don't have access to all popular browsers; and, it takes a long time to test all browsers. I hope somebody had written an article before or know the answer for my question. (I mean, I don't want (and I can't, actually) you or others to test it for me)